# pandas loc doesn't change every column value in given range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to use pandas' loc to change some column's value.

I have a main df which has about 200k rows with the following structure:
[col1, col2, col3, col4, col5].

I need to change some of the values of col4 and col5 based on the number of rows with value val. In pseudocode would something like this:

```py
for each row in dataframe:
    if col2 == value:
        then col4 and col5 change its value
```

I made a method to create smaller dataframes of each col2 values to work with them to change col4 and col5 and then concatenate them. In this smaller dataframe I'm using pandas loc like that:

```py
smaller_df.loc[range_to_change_col4, col4] = new_col4_value
smaller_df.loc[range_to_change_col5, col5] = new_col5_value
```

Data sample:

```
Original ->
class;id;url;aug;iterations
image_class;1;image_url;0;0
Expected ->
class;id;url;aug;iterations
image_class;1;image_url;1;1
```

Code sample:

```
# Number of images I need to augment / 
# number of images I already have
if images_to_add / df.shape[0] < 1:
        # Random index' rows
        to_update = df.sample(
            n = to_add, # number of images I need to create
            replace=True, 
            random_state=1
            ).index
        # real image will be augmented
        df.loc[to_update,'aug'] = 1
        # How many times real image will be augmented 
        df.loc[to_update,'iterations'] = 1
```

My problem is that not in every smaller df all rows update its value. I'm relatively new to pandas and I don't what's the problem. Maybe memory problem? Any idea about how could I avoid this?

Comment: You can using pandas functions to solve this. and just do a replace(). If you add a sample of your dataframe and what you want to achieve then we can help you better

Comment: This is still not clear. How about showing a sample of your data. And indicate what your expected results are. You have to help us to help you.
Pandas has pure functions to achieve manipulations where you don't need to use loops. check the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use assign, like:

```
.assign(new_colum_name=lambda x: x["colom name"] * 1.3,
    new_colum_name=lambda x: x["colom name"] + x["colom name"],
    new_colum_name=lambda x: x["colom name"].str.replace("2", "3") + x["colom name"]),
    new_colum_name=lambda x: np.where(x["Voorraad"] > 8, 8, x["Voorraad"]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: in `df.sample` the problem was the `replace` parameter; setting it to `False` solved the issue and now I can change every value.

The new code is

```
# Number of images I need to augment / 
# number of images I already have
if images_to_add / df.shape[0] < 1:
        # Random index' rows
        to_update = df.sample(
            n = to_add, # number of images I need to create
            replace=False, 
            random_state=1
            ).index
        # real image will be augmented
        df.loc[to_update,'aug'] = 1
        # How many times real image will be augmented 
        df.loc[to_update,'iterations'] = 1
```